# Ignore tests in Junit5

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I have a parametrizedTest using Junit5. I would like to ignore the test for a subset of the parameters.

Question : 
Given a set of parameters, one of them is a boolean called ignoreTest. i would like to ignore the test for the set of parameters in which ignoreTest is true.

Is there a way to do that? One way is to put all the code of test in if(!ignoreTest). but this will hide the fact that we are ignoring that test in the Junit report.
Is there a way to do better ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your or any prototypical parameterized test so that a potential answerer can use that as basis for their solution?

Answer (score 1):

I use `assumeTrue` for this, something like:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource(TestEnum.class)
public void test(TestEnum params) {
    assumeTrue(!params.ignoreTest, "Test ignored.");
    ...
}
```

It shows up as skipped in the test report.